# First Class Japan Rail Pass on Trains Without First Class

Tags: tickets, japan, luxury, japan-rail, jr-passes

Can I use a first class Japan Rail pass to board trains that don't have a first class carriage?

Answer (score 19):

**Yes.**  [japanrailpass.net](http://www.japanrailpass.net/eng/en004.html):

> Most JR trains have Ordinary Cars (coach class) while many
>   long-distance trains also offer Green Cars (superior class). **With a
>   Green-type JAPAN RAIL PASS you can use either class.**

Note that there's only a *Green* Japan Rail Pass, not a "first class" one.  This means you can use Green Cars (roughly, business class), but you cannot use the [Gran Class](http://www.japan-rail-pass.com/japan-by-rail/travel-tips/granclass) (roughly, first class) cars without paying additional surcharges.